# does `transform_lookup` save space?

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to link several Altair charts that share aspects of the same data. I can do this by merging all the data into one data frame, but because of the nature of the data the merged data frame is much larger than is needed to have two separate data frames for each of the two charts. This is because the columns unique to each chart have many repeated rows for each entry in the shared column.

Would using `transform_lookup` save space over just using the merged data frame, or does `transform_lookup` end up doing the whole merge internally?

Answer (score 1):

No, the entire dataset is still included in the vegaspec when you use `transform_lookup`. You can see this by printing the json spec of the charts you create. [With the example from the docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/lookup.html):

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data

people = data.lookup_people().head(3)
people
```

```sh
    name    age height
0   Alan    25  180
1   George  32  174
2   Fred    39  182
```

```
groups = data.lookup_groups().head(3)
groups
```

```sh
    group   person
0   1   Alan
1   1   George
2   1   Fred
```

With pandas merge:

```
merged = pd.merge(groups, people, how='left',
                  left_on='person', right_on='name')

print(alt.Chart(merged).mark_bar().encode(
    x='mean(age):Q',
    y='group:O'
).to_json())
```

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json",
  "config": {
    "view": {
      "continuousHeight": 300,
      "continuousWidth": 400
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "name": "data-b41b97ffc89b39c92e168871d447e720"
  },
  "datasets": {
    "data-b41b97ffc89b39c92e168871d447e720": [
      {
        "age": 25,
        "group": 1,
        "height": 180,
        "name": "Alan",
        "person": "Alan"
      },
      {
        "age": 32,
        "group": 1,
        "height": 174,
        "name": "George",
        "person": "George"
      },
      {
        "age": 39,
        "group": 1,
        "height": 182,
        "name": "Fred",
        "person": "Fred"
      }
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "aggregate": "mean",
      "field": "age",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "group",
      "type": "ordinal"
    }
  },
  "mark": "bar"
}
```

With transform lookup all the data is there but as to separate dataset (so technically it takes a little bit of more space with the additional braces and the transform):

```
print(alt.Chart(groups).mark_bar().encode(
    x='mean(age):Q',
    y='group:O'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='person',
    from_=alt.LookupData(data=people, key='name',
                         fields=['age'])
).to_json())
```

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json",
  "config": {
    "view": {
      "continuousHeight": 300,
      "continuousWidth": 400
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "name": "data-5fe242a79352d1fe243b588af570c9c6"
  },
  "datasets": {
    "data-2b374d1509415e1d327c3a7521f8117c": [
      {
        "age": 25,
        "height": 180,
        "name": "Alan"
      },
      {
        "age": 32,
        "height": 174,
        "name": "George"
      },
      {
        "age": 39,
        "height": 182,
        "name": "Fred"
      }
    ],
    "data-5fe242a79352d1fe243b588af570c9c6": [
      {
        "group": 1,
        "person": "Alan"
      },
      {
        "group": 1,
        "person": "George"
      },
      {
        "group": 1,
        "person": "Fred"
      }
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "aggregate": "mean",
      "field": "age",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "group",
      "type": "ordinal"
    }
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "transform": [
    {
      "from": {
        "data": {
          "name": "data-2b374d1509415e1d327c3a7521f8117c"
        },
        "fields": [
          "age",
          "height"
        ],
        "key": "name"
      },
      "lookup": "person"
    }
  ]
}
```

When `transform_lookup` can save space is if you use it with the URLs of two dataset:

```
people = data.lookup_people.url
groups = data.lookup_groups.url
print(alt.Chart(groups).mark_bar().encode(
    x='mean(age):Q',
    y='group:O'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='person',
    from_=alt.LookupData(data=people, key='name',
                         fields=['age'])
).to_json())
```

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json",
  "config": {
    "view": {
      "continuousHeight": 300,
      "continuousWidth": 400
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/lookup_groups.csv"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "aggregate": "mean",
      "field": "age",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "group",
      "type": "ordinal"
    }
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "transform": [
    {
      "from": {
        "data": {
          "url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/lookup_people.csv"
        },
        "fields": [
          "age",
          "height"
        ],
        "key": "name"
      },
      "lookup": "person"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I actually interpret this the opposite. If `people` had a repeated entry in one of the columns (say 5 groups for each people along with another column with `group_name` such that there were three people but 15 rows in `people`), then this makes it look like it **would** save space.

Comment: @JesseBloom I can't visualize your example, could you post the json specs of that example as another answer showing when they're shorter with the transform?